# PM2 ecosystem.config.js nested environment variables

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

I have an env variable in my `ecosystem.config.js` like this

```
ORGANIZATION: {
                "b0fd9120-deb7-55t6-b269-c1622a43e9af": {
                     ORG_NAME: "org 1",
                     RAZORPAY: {
                         KEY: 'randomkey1',
                         SECRET:'randomsecret1'
            },
        },
               "ab5003c0-deb7-11e9-334s-c1622ayyy9af": {
                    ORG_NAME: "org 2",
                    RAZORPAY: {
                        KEY: 'randomkey2',
                         SECRET:'randomsecret2'
            },
        }
    },
```

Complete `ecosystem.config.js` looks like this

```
module.exports = {

    apps: [

        // First application
        {
            name: 'Myapp',
            script: 'startserver.sh',
            max_memory_restart: '1024M',
            env_production: {
                DATABASE: 'a',
                USERNAME: 'a',
                PASSWORD: 'a',
                HOST: 'd',
                PORT: '2929',
                DB_PORT: '5432',
                ORGANIZATION: {
                    "b0fd9120-deb7-55t6-b269-c1622a43e9af": {
                        ORG_NAME: "org1",
                        RAZORPAY: {
                            KEY: 'dd',
                            SECRET: 'dd'
                        },
                    },
                    "ab5003c0-deb7-11e9-334s-c1622ayyy9af": {
                        ORG_NAME: "org2",
                        RAZORPAY: {
                            KEY: 'dd',
                            SECRET: 'dd'
                        },
                    }
                },
            },

            env_staging: {
                DATABASE: 'a',
                USERNAME: 'a',
                PASSWORD: 'a',
                HOST: 'd',
                PORT: '2929',
                DB_PORT: '5432',
                ORGANIZATION: {
                    "b0fd9120-deb7-55t6-b269-c1622a43e9af": {
                        ORG_NAME: "org1",
                        RAZORPAY: {
                            KEY: 'dd',
                            SECRET: 'dd'
                        },
                    },
                    "ab5003c0-deb7-11e9-334s-c1622ayyy9af": {
                        ORG_NAME: "org2",
                        RAZORPAY: {
                            KEY: 'dd',
                            SECRET: 'dd'
                        },
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    ],
};
```

`startserver.sh` runs `npm start`

I'm trying to access `RAZORPAY.KEY` by using

`process.env.ORGANIZATION["b0fd9120-deb7-55t6-b269-c1622a43e9af"].RAZORPAY.KEY`

but failing to get with error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'RAZORPAY' of undefined

I start my app with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env staging --update-env`

Every other env variable outside `ORGANIZATION` is accessible.

Comment: Can we see the entire `ecosystem.config.js` file? And what command are you using to run the application?

Comment: @AdamPatterson take a look at the updated question.

Comment: are you using dotenv package ? If yes, there's a chance your pm2 vars are not being read

Comment: @Sriram. No I'm not. every other flattened variable outside of ORGANIZATION can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Any property of `process.env` contains just strings. Environment variables cannot be objects, they'll always be strings (except you patch the node environment somehow).

If pm2 can handle declaration of objects as strings, it will probably be JSON.stringified, so you'll have a serialized JSON object in `process.env.ORGANIZATION` which you can parse:

```
const ORGANIZATION = JSON.parse(process.env.ORGANIZATION);
console.log(ORGANIZATION["b0fd9120-deb7-55t6-b269-c1622a43e9af"].RAZORPAY.KEY);
```